# Angular2/4 Telephone Validation

Tags: html, regex, validation, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I am trying to implement a form in Angular 2/4. There is a field for Telephone number. I used a regular expression as

```
pattern="^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[- (]*(\d{3})[- )]*(\d{3})[- ]*(\d{4})(?: *[x/#]{1}(\d+))?\s*$"
```

in the corresponding input field. It accepts almost all the formats but not the following:

1. 754-3010 (Local)
2. (541) 754-3010 (Domestic)
3. +1-541-754-3010 (international)

More over it should accept +, -, (, and ) characters.

Hope some one can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may make a part of the regex optional using an optional non-capturing group.

Use

```
^\s*(?:\+?\d{1,3})?[- (]*\d{3}(?:[- )]*\d{3})?[- ]*\d{4}(?: *[x/#]\d+)?\s*$
                              ^^^           ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZMBWPp/1)

Note that `{1}` is redundant, you may remove it.

As for the capturing groups, you may keep your original ones if you need them, but if you are just validating, I'd rather remove them.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:\+?\d{1,3})?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\+?` - an optional (1 or 0) `+` symbol
  - `\d{1,3}` - any 1 to 3 digits
- `[- (]*`  - a `-`, space or `(`
- `\d{3}` -  any 3 digits
- `(?:[- )]*\d{3})?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `[- )]*` - 0+ `-`, spaces or `)`
  - `\d{3}` - any 3 digits
- `[- ]*` - 0+ spaces or `-`
- `\d{4}` - any 4 digits
- `(?: *[x/#]\d+)?`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks a lot for this one.